# Replacing assembly instruction changes other instructions

Tags: c++

I am trying to place a call instruction at a function to simulate a hook, so i should be replacing 6 bytes in the beginning of the function to place my call which is 2 bytes for the opcode and a dword for the address. however here is the disassembly of the function before i hook it

```
void realFunction()
{
00B533C0  push        ebp  
00B533C1  mov         ebp,esp  
00B533C3  sub         esp,0C0h  
00B533C9  push        ebx  
00B533CA  push        esi  
00B533CB  push        edi  
00B533CC  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
00B533D2  mov         ecx,30h  
00B533D7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00B533DC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    MessageBox(NULL, "realFunction()", "Trace", MB_OK);
00B533DE  mov         esi,esp  
00B533E0  push        0  
00B533E2  push        0B56488h  
00B533E7  push        0B56490h  
00B533EC  push        0  
00B533EE  call        dword ptr ds:[0B5613Ch]  
00B533F4  cmp         esi,esp  
00B533F6  call        _RTC_CheckEsp (0B53A10h)  
}
```

and strangely here is it after i just replace 6 bytes

```
void realFunction()
{
00B533C0  call        fakeFunction (0B52EF0h)  
00B533C5  rol         byte ptr [eax],0 <-- 
00B533C8  add         byte ptr [ebx+56h],dl <--
00B533CB  push        edi <--
00B533CC  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h] <--
00B533D2  mov         ecx,30h  
00B533D7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00B533DC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    MessageBox(NULL, "realFunction()", "Trace", MB_OK);
00B533DE  mov         esi,esp  
00B533E0  push        0  
00B533E2  push        0B56488h  
00B533E7  push        0B56490h  
00B533EC  push        0  
00B533EE  call        dword ptr ds:[0B5613Ch]  
00B533F4  cmp         esi,esp  
00B533F6  call        _RTC_CheckEsp (0B53A10h)  
}
```

code for the hook

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void realFunction()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "realFunction()", "Trace", MB_OK);
}

__declspec(naked) void fakeFunction()
{
    __asm {
        pushad;
        pushfd;
    }

    MessageBox(NULL, "fakeFunction()", "Trace", MB_OK);

    __asm{
        popfd;
        popad;
        ret; //This should return back and resumes the execution of the original function;
    }
}

void main()
{
    DWORD size = sizeof(double);
    DWORD oldProtection;
    DWORD realFunctionAddr = (DWORD)realFunction;
    DWORD fakeFunctionAddr = (DWORD)fakeFunction;

    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)realFunctionAddr, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);
    *((PBYTE)(realFunctionAddr)) = 0xE8;
    *((PDWORD)(realFunctionAddr + 1)) = fakeFunctionAddr - realFunctionAddr - 5;
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)fakeFunctionAddr, size, oldProtection, &oldProtection);

    realFunction();

    while (true){
        cin.get();
    }
}
```

I want to understand why this happens, why not just the 6 bytes i replaced are changed ?

Comment: I think you're overwriting a partial assembly instruction, leading to the instruction right after the 6th byte becoming something other than what it was previously

Comment: @MichaelGazonda mmm the original instruction is push ebp which must be 0xFF, .... 0x00 and it is 6 bytes too right ? i am just replacing a 6 bytes with 6 bytes

Comment: C0 - C4 = 1 instruction (5 bytes), C5 - C7 = 1 instruction (3 bytes) - 6 bytes doesn't sound like the right number here...

Comment: are you replacing at C3, because it looks like that's the 6 byte place you want, and it looks like you're replacing at C0

Comment: @MichaelGazonda i think i understand something wrong here, i though each assembly instruction is by default a 6 bytes instruction and that even if the opcode are small the rest is getting filled with 0x00... so how could i determine that C3 is the place to go ? and yeah i can't find C4 address above how could you conclude it ? i think you calculate it by the difference between the hexadecimal values right ?

Comment: You'll need to disassemble the code (probably as it's running) to find out how big the instructions are where you're patching code. It's the only way to know that you're patching at the right place.

Comment: The length of CPU instructions ranges from 1 byte to many more than 6 bytes.

Comment: Also, if you're doing this for some kind of commercial product rather than a fun exercise, I recommend looking into patching code atomically. As in, you inject 6 bytes, but does that happen in one instruction or two?

Comment: @MichaelGazonda i am doing that just for learning. so from what i understand now is that i need to find a good place to fit my 6 bytes (although they are 5 in the code above) and the least significant place to add it would be `C3` because it has mmm 6 bytes in it so what i should do is placing my call instruction, nop the rest and it should be fine. Also do you determine the size of an instruction by calculating the difference between the hex addresses ?

Comment: Yes, that's how you can tell how long an instruction is.

Comment: Instructions without operands tend to be small, like 1 or 2 bytes.  Instructions with operands tend to be longer, because the opcode is followed by the operand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the `sub esp,0C0h` instruction begins at address 00B533C3, but the next instruction `push ebx` begins at address 00B533C9.  You have overwritten addresses 00B533C0 through 00B533C5, so immediately after your 6 bytes you are in the middle of the `sub esp,0C0h` instruction.

The disassembler has no way of knowing that a certain byte is garbage and not an instruction, so it tries to interpret the bytes as instructions, as best as it can, and what you see is, of course, nonsensical instructions.  After a while it just so happens (by coincidence) that the end of a nonsensical instruction coincides with the end of an actual instruction that used to be there, so from that point on the disassembler interprets instructions successfully, that's why the remainder of your function looks okay.

If you look at the actual bytes, and not at the assembly language mnemonic interpretations of these bytes, you will see that nothing funky is going on.

(Except, perhaps, for the fact that you appear to have replaced 5, not 6 bytes.)

Comment: but if that is the case so i already replaced `C3` with my 6 bytes and i am now left with a half or less of the sub esp, 0C0h instuction right ?

Comment: Yes, `rol byte ptr [eax],0` is the middle of the `sub esp,0C0h` instruction.

Comment: You probably do not need to add any NOPs, because I do not suppose that your fake function ever intends to return.  (If it does, you are going to have a crash, because you have destroyed the entry code of the original function.)  But if you add NOPs until 00B533C8 then after the NOPs you will see the old instructions as they used to be instead of garbage.

Comment: Yea i see the normal instructions now, so why did my code throw an exception of `privileged instruction` when fake function gets executed ? and yeah the instructions seem to be fine now. also i am calling pushad and pushfd to save the old instructions and i immediately pop them before i return so why it should crash ?

Comment: I do not know that.  You will have to throw a debugger at it to see what happens.  Are you sure your fake function is at 0B52EF0h?  Could it be that your fake function returned?  If it did, you will certainly have a crash, as I explained above.  Anyway, that would be the subject of another stackoverflow question.  This one has been answered, no?

Comment: You made my day, i feel i am 1 more step ahead toward learning this thing :D, i just want to tell you that the exception happens because the debugger hits a strange instruction called `hlt`

Comment: Oh, yes, that will do it!

Comment: i will ask another question i need you there :P

Comment: I need to go to sleep now.  But believe me, there are lots of brilliant people here on stackoverflow who are just as good or better than me.  For example, Michael Gazonda also understood what was going on.